# How to preprocess data in a data table? (e.g. change a value in each row for some feature)

Tags: orange

I Have a general question - how to preprocess data in Orange. E.g. I want to do something with each row value of some feature. How can I do this visually? And how can I do this via Python Script?

So far, I have only some ideas how to do this via python script:

Here is my code:

```
minimum = min(list(map(lambda row: row[0], in_data))).value

from copy import deepcopy
out_data = deepcopy(in_data)

for row in out_data:
    row[0].value = row[0].value - minimum
```

But it fails, because seems like the Value object is immutable... 
Is there any way to create my own Value object with new data, and then do something like:

```
out_data = list(map(lambda row: Value(row[0].variable, [row[0].value - minimum]) + row[1:], in_data))
```

I am also interested in a "Visual widget-based" alternative, if it exists...

Answer (score 2):

To scale the data, you can use [Preprocess](http://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/visual-programming/widgets/data/preprocess.html) widget. To construct new features, e.g.

```
new_feature = old_feature - some_values
```

you can use [Feature Constructor](http://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/visual-programming/widgets/data/featureconstructor.html) widget.

Comment: Feature Constructor seems to match my needs, but how can I implement something like this: `new_feature = old_feature - <min value of old feature>`?

Comment: I don't know. Whoever designed the widget didn't seem to account for this use case. The project seems pretty active, you should submit an enhancement request on their issue tracker: https://github.com/biolab/orange3

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked for my case:

```
minimum = min(list(map(lambda row: row[0].value, in_data)))

from copy import deepcopy
out_data = deepcopy(in_data)

import Orange
for i in range(len(out_data)):
    out_data[i,0] = Orange.data.Value(out_data[i,0].variable, out_data[i,0].value - minimum)
```

Interesting is that in order to plot the out_data, I needed additional "Select Columns" widget before "Scatter Plot".

In addition I couldn't combine two out_data (one from one source and one from another) on one Scatter Plot... But this seems to be an other question...